# Is that ok to transmit data between fragments like that?

Tags: android, android-fragments

There are one main activity(`A`) and two fragments(`F1` and `F2`). Both of fragments have got `setRetainInstance(true);` statement. `F2` has a static field `b`. `A` runs `F1` at first. `F1` runs `F2` using fragment manager after button click or something. So I create `F2` intsance, set field `b` with setter method and put it to a fragment manager. Is that a good approach or not? Is using bundle the only "good" way to transmit data between fragments? Also what if `b` is not static? Does that change the situation?

Comment: I don't understand the question but to address a couple of points... Firstly a `Fragment` (like an `Activity` should *NEVER* expose any `public static` fields or methods with the intention of any other app component accessing them. Secondly, unless `F2` is a child `Fragment` of `F1` then all communication between them should be done via the `Activity`. A `Fragment` should *NEVER* create another `Fragment` unless the second is a child.

Comment: try eventbus otto  http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: Closers please explain the reason

Comment: I voted to close because your question is unclear (I chose "Unclear what you're asking" as my reason to close. The first line of my comment explains that although I waited around 20-30 minutes for you to add extra information before voting to close as you hadn't responded to my comment  or added any further information. The official Android dev docs clearly explain about Fragment <=> Fragment communication being done via the Activity and, as with Activities starting other Activities, the approved (safe) method is with bundled data and not direct access through static fields or methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is **ALSO** a way to transfer data between `Fragments` **BUT** should only be used at the time when we need to `Retain` the `State` of the `Fragment` i.e., when ever we want to save the state of `Fragment` such as `Button` property `visible` and `invisible` states we use `setRetainInstance(true);`

Answer (score 0):

**Fragment** is meant to be **independent and reusable**. You should not use static for such operations. Static field is not comfortable with **memory** management too. Use **bundle** which can be helpful in many ways including **savedInstanceState**

Just imagine a situation when you need to reuse Fragment B for multiple times in single screen. That static field will not be able to store multiple values.isn't it ?

You should simply follow standard practices as they have designed it to handle many scenario which we may not know. Simply go for bundle.